# How to get Instruments attached to simulator for UI Automation Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments

I'm trying to figure out how to do automated UI testing so that I can test my app for regression errors as I make changes and such. I'm following the instructions found in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html). I built my app in Xcode and it is running in the iOS simulator.

I opened Instruments and chose the iOS Automation instrument. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get Instruments to run the script on my iOS app in the sim. When I first create the Automation instrument the target drop down just says "lkj" but if I try to choose the sim as my target, it tells me that the Automation instrument doesn't allow attaching.

[image]

How do I get Instruments to run my test on my iOS app?

I tried just running it with the "lkj" target selected and I got a weird error involving some random guy's name (I'm assuming he's a dev for Instruments or something?)

> Path not found
>   '/Users/jonathan_morgan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/lkj-randomstringofcharacters/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/lkj.app/lkj

Comment: An alternative solution for you would be to take a look into KIF: https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to attach your target to the simulator and run your UIAutomation scripts is to profile the app. **Xcode** - **Product** - **Build For** - **Profiling** and then select the **Automation** template.

Another way to attach the target, if you've already built the app on your simulator. Is to select **Choose Target** and then go to the following location **/Users/[yourUserName]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[iOSVersion]/Applications/[AppFolder]/[NameOfYourTarget]**

For more info, you can take a look at this blog which is pretty detailed http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/04/08/ios-automated-tests-with-uiautomation

Hope it helps.

Comment: Had the same problem and this helped me.  I think what happened in my case (and probably the OP) was that I launched Instruments without first building for Profiling.  Instruments freaked out and found this hard-coded developer's path...somewhere.  Definitely a UI bug in Instruments though, and a weird one at that.